# Python - method of a class with an optional argument and default value a class member

Tags: python

I have something like this (I know this code doesn't work, but it's the closer to what I want to achieve):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def method(self, a=self.a):
        print a

myClass = A()

myClass.method('b') # print b
myClass.method() # print a
```

What I've done so far, but I do not like it, is:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def method(self, a=None):
        if a is None:
            a = self.a

        print a

myClass = A()

myClass.method('b') # print b
myClass.method() # print a
```

Comment: Well, it's the canonical solution. Most languages don't allow `a=self.a` or equivalent for parameter defaults…

Comment: If you're not concerned about passing in *falsey* values and possible resulting side effects, this shorthand will do too: `print a or self.a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated at **definition time**. By the time the class and method are defined `self.a` is not.

Your working code example is actually the only clean way of achieving this behavior.

Comment: Okay, thanks. TBH I find it quite verbose, but my Python-fu is bad, so if you say it is the clean way to do it, I'll go with it...

Answer (score 2):

The default is evaluated at method definition time, i.e. when the interpreter executes the class body, which usually happens only once.  Assigning a dynamic value as default can only happen within the method body, and the approach you use is perfectly fine.